# Get Min, Max and Average from Amazon cloud search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to retrieve Min, Max and Average on CloudSearch Column (index) in search result. I can not do it in code since I am only fetching 1000 records and Aggregation is required on all data searched by query.

I tried with Min expression but it returns for each record.

Any idea what query or Configuration I would required?

Comment: Are you trying to get CloudSearch to compute the average of some indexed field for you? If so, I don't think that is possible -- that's more like data analysis and not really search-related functionality.

Comment: Yes thats what I am trying for, get avg of an index field.

Comment: You can't; it's a search engine not map-reduce... it doesn't do computation on your data.

Comment: Thanks! I used alternative for same.Will post here once I test it out.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this by calculating on .net side.